# Pyspark: how to convert unix timestamp to date while I am reading a csv file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a .csv that looks like the following

```
Timestamp,   Name,    Value  
1577862435, BatteryA, 0.25  
1577915618, BatteryB, 0.50  
1577839734, BatteryC, 0.34
```

I define a schema

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("timestamp", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("Name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Value", FloatType(), True)])

df = spark.read.format('csv').option("delimiter", "\t").schema(schema).load("myFile.csv")
```

How can I read directly the Unix timestamp in form of date while I am reading it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TimestampType`:

```
schema = StructType([
StructField("timestamp", TimestampType(), True),
StructField("Name", StringType(), True),
StructField("Value", FloatType(), True)])

df = spark.read.format('csv').option("delimiter", "\t").schema(schema).load("myFile.csv")
```

---

*Update*
So apparently, you can't directly read epoch timestamp to a TimestampType, it must be converted to long before that.

I suggest you do:

```
schema = StructType([
StructField("timestamp", LongType(), True),
StructField("Name", StringType(), True),
StructField("Value", FloatType(), True)])

df = spark.read.format('csv').option("delimiter", "\t").schema(schema).load("myFile.csv")
df = df.withColumn("timestamp", df["timestamp"].cast(TimestampType()))
```

Comment: you are right. I tested it myself just now. look at my updated answer

Comment: I get this error `NameError: name 'res' is not defined`

Comment: sorry, it was a copy-past mistake. look above

Comment: now I get `NameError: name 'withColumn' is not defined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210281/discussion-between-dvir-samuel-and-emax).